Ubuntu won't boot when plugged in
I installed Ubuntu (currently Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) a few months ago on my Dell Precision 5570. When the power cord is disconnected, either the USB C that came with the laptop or a docking station, the system won't boot. It gets to a screen with a cursor like this image:

Booting without a power cord works just fine, and I can connect the cable after the OS boots and everything is normal. I've tried looking into the editing the GRUB menu, but I haven't made any changes.

FYI:  If your system still reports as 22.04.3, you've got a problem or have not been applying security fixes/upgrades.  This https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/ show show the ISO release date of 22.04.4, but installed 22.04 systems upgraded BEFORE that date.  Check you've applied security fixes & your stated release, as that shows a problem (even if not what you're asking about).
